# Move JButton every click (KeyEvent)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, keyevent

I was trying to create a simple game. For this, i created a JButton that moves down and up, but it only works one time when i click the Down and Up arrows. Can i make it moves every time I click these arrows? I have already tried the while loop, but it didn't work.

Here is the code:

```java
jb = new JButton();
jb.setBounds(40, 40, 60, 40);
jb.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
jb.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        int y = 40;
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            y += 4;
            jb.setBounds(40, y, 60, 40);
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            y -= 4;
            jb.setBounds(40, y, 60, 40);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You must keep the reference of the older position by changing it scope to the class instead of the method you using:

```
        int y = 40;
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
```

This is the necessary to make it work

Answer (score 1):

As already stated by Marcos, you need to know "where" the button is currently, before you update it.

However, I would recommend using the "actual" location of the button instead of some variable, which may not represent the true state, for example...

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    int y = jb.getY();
    
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        y += 4;
        jb.setBounds(40, y, 60, 40);
    } 
    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        y -= 4;
        jb.setBounds(40, y, 60, 40);
    } 
}
```

Having said that, I would avoid using `KeyListener` and as a personal preference, try and decouple the workflow.

Instead, I'd make use of the [Key Bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), and try and make the movement workflow more decoupled (less constrained to the physical control), but, that's me.

Comment: `getY()` → `jb.getY()` And when we are at simplifying it, I’d use `jb.setLocation(jb.getX(), y);`

Comment: @Holger Actually that should be `jb.setLocation(jb.getX() + delta, y)`, otherwise you're just putting back in its original location ... but for me, I'd probably wouldn't be using components for this purpose, but that's me

Comment: ahem, `x` is supposed to at the original value. It’s `y` that is changed. What do you mean with “using components”?

Comment: @Holger Yes - my point was, `value + delta` otherwise it won't move as you'd just be reapplying the same value, regardless.  Swing components aren't really meant to be used this way, they have a lot of baggage and require a lot of careful handling, normally this is handled by the layout management workflow.  For a "game" I would consider using a custom painting route, but, that's me

Comment: I suggested to replace `jb.setBounds(40, y, 60, 40);` with `jb.setLocation(jb.getX(), y);`, assuming the code of your answer to be otherwise unchanged, so `y` does already contain the updated value. The x is not supposed to change, it’s always `40` in the original code, but using `jb.getX()` instead of a hardcoded value is preferable. Yes, a custom painting routine would be much better, I just couldn’t match that concept with the phrase “using components”.

Comment: @Holger Sure, but that assumes that you want to keep it at that X position, and that it's current position is correct, it might not have been set yet, since I only have a "out-of-context" code snippet, I went for the smallest change possible to make the point. I *"wouldn't be using components for this purpose"* basically means that, I, personally, would approach this problem different and wouldn't make use of a `JButton` in this way - as I said, Swing components tend to have a set live cycle, which is typically managed by the layout management API and aren't typically well suited for this IMHO

Comment: Well, I was only using the existing code of the question and answer as starting point where x is always `40`. That surely never supports x movement. In contrast, using `jb.getX()` *does* support it as it wouldn’t cancel out changes made at a different code location. Anyway, I understood the point of the custom painting routine, I would prefer it too. I only didn’t get it when I read your first comment.

Comment: @Holger Sure, but how do you know that the position has been set (before the event handler has been invoked)?  Not saying your wrong and if I had more context, I might even agree ;)